# Cannot build opencv 2.4 on a 64 bit mac for C++ project in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

After looking around a lot and trying every option I found on SO, I'm a little confused about how to get the OpenCV library for architecture x86_64 loaded on my Mac.  Here's a little bit of background info:

[image]

The first folder contains the **Android SDK**.  The second is the **iPhone framework**, which uses **i386** and **armv7** architectures.

Now, I want to create a simple "Hello World" **C++** application in **Xcode** which needs the correct library for **x86_64** architecture.

I've looked at this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/yonasstephenfyp2013/updates/tutorialinstallingopencvonmacosxmountainlion) as well as others' posted steps as follows:

- mkdir build
- cd build
- cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
- make -j8
- sudo make install

With all version (except OpenCV-2.4.6.1), the process fails at "make -j8".  I get the same error every time:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.dylib

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "___sincos_stret", referenced from:

      cv::RotatedRect::points(cv::Point_<float>*) const in matrix.cpp.o

      cv::RotatedRect::boundingRect() const in matrix.cpp.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_core.2.4.3.dylib] Error 1

make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2

make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

[ 28%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfThreading.cpp.o

[ 28%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfTileDescriptionAttribute.cpp.o

[ 28%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfTiledInputFile.cpp.o

[ 29%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfTiledMisc.cpp.o

[ 29%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfTiledOutputFile.cpp.o

[ 29%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfTiledRgbaFile.cpp.o

[ 29%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfTileOffsets.cpp.o

[ 29%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfTimeCode.cpp.o

[ 29%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfTimeCodeAttribute.cpp.o

[ 29%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfVecAttribute.cpp.o

[ 29%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfVersion.cpp.o

[ 29%] [ 30%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfWav.cpp.o

Building CXX object 3rdparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp.o

Linking CXX static library ../lib/libIlmImf.a

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/libIlmImf.a(IlmThread.cpp.o) has no symbols

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/libIlmImf.a(IlmThreadMutex.cpp.o) has no symbols

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/libIlmImf.a(IlmThreadSemaphore.cpp.o) has no symbols

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/libIlmImf.a(IlmThreadSemaphorePosixCompat.cpp.o) has no symbols

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/libIlmImf.a(IlmThread.cpp.o) has no symbols

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/libIlmImf.a(IlmThreadMutex.cpp.o) has no symbols

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/libIlmImf.a(IlmThreadSemaphore.cpp.o) has no symbols

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/libIlmImf.a(IlmThreadSemaphorePosixCompat.cpp.o) has no symbols

[ 30%] Built target IlmImf

make: *** [all] Error 2

pdls-mbp:build pdl$
```

With OpenCV-2.4.6.1, the process fails at "sudo make install" and I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.dylib

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "___sincos_stret", referenced from:

      cv::RotatedRect::points(cv::Point_<float>*) const in matrix.cpp.o

      cv::RotatedRect::boundingRect() const in matrix.cpp.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib] Error 1

make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

Lucys-MacBook-Pro:build pdl$
```

When I installed OpenCV using Homebrew, opencv was installed in use/local/opt/opencv and I can see all of the dylib files under the lib folder:

[image: Contents of lib folder]

All of this completely confuses me, because I think all I need is a .a library file, no?

I have found the dylib files that were installed with HomeBrew in /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib but when I try to choose frameworks and libraries to add, they do not show up in the list.  Instead, this is all I see:

[image: Choose frameworks and libraries to add:]

Aldo, been following this [MacPorts tutorial](http://tilomitra.com/opencv-on-mac-osx/).

Comment: What's wrong with DYLIBS? Just load them dynamically.

Comment: I couldn't access them in the Link Binary With Libraries browser.  After installing MacPorts and following trojanfoe's instructions, it just worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [macports](http://macports.org)?  It has opencv 2.4.8 [available](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=opencv).

So after [installing macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php), all that nonsense you've been through, is reduced to:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port install opencv
```

if you want a *variant* or two, for example OpenCL and Python support, then that would be:

```
$ sudo port install opencv +opencl +python27
```

and the binaries/libraries/whatever will be installed into `/opt/local/...`.